# Failed Laravel job causing PostgreSQL database locks

Tags: postgresql, laravel-7

**Background** - I recently transitioned a website from the Zend Framework to Laravel 7.x.  The website has about 10,000 active daily users and relies heavily on background jobs to perform certain actions such as importing files.

**The Problem (TL:DR; version)** - Since launching the upgrade last week, I've noticed that a table in the database will become deadlocked which can cause the entire site to slow to a halt. The deadlocked table always seems to revolve around background jobs.

**The Process**

I have a worker queue using `Redis` set up with the following parameters:

In my Procfile: `worker: php /app/artisan queue:restart && php /app/artisan queue:work redis --tries=3 --timeout=30`

In `config/queue.php`:

```
'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => 5,
        ],
```

I created a background job in Laravel that handles the import process.  When a user initiates an import, the details about that import are saved into a `processes` table. I use this table to monitor the job progress so the user knows when their import has finished. This table schema is as follows:

```
Table "public.processes"
    Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                Default                
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------
 id           | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('processes_id_seq'::regclass)
 user_id      | integer                     |           | not null | 
 process_name | character varying(30)       |           | not null | 
 process_id   | integer                     |           | not null | 
 params       | text                        |           |          | 
 tool         | character varying(20)       |           |          | 
 completed    | boolean                     |           |          | false
 viewed       | boolean                     |           |          | false
 failed       | boolean                     |           |          | false
 failed_text  | text                        |           |          | 
 modified_at  | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 created_at   | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | now()
Indexes:
    "processes_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "pro_user_id" btree (user_id)
```

When a user imports a file, it runs the following function which adds an entry into the `processes` table, dispatches the import process and then redirects them to a "loading" page which checks the `processes` table every couple of seconds to see if the `completed` or `failed` column has been set to `true`

```
<?php

public function load(Request $request)
    {
        $proObj = new Process();
        $name = session('user.id').'_'.date('U');
        $params = http_build_query($request->all());
        
        $proObj->add_process(array(
                                'user_id'=>session('user.id'),
                                'process_name'=>$name,
                                'process_id'=>0,
                                'params'=>$params,
                                'tool'=>'import'
                            ));
        ImportFile::dispatch(['user_id'=> session('user.id'), 'process_name' => $name]);
        
        // Redirect to Loading Page
        return redirect('/process/importing?n='.$name);
    }
?>
```

The `ImportFile` job's handle function looks like this:

```
<?php

public function handle()
    {
        $user_id = $this->args['user_id'];
        $process_name = $this->args['process_name'];
        
        $iObj = new Import();
        $pObj = new Process();
        
        //get the data for this process
        $result = $pObj->get_process($user_id,$process_name);

        if($result) {
            $process_id = $result->id;
            //turn the string of $_POST data back into an array
            $post = [];
            parse_str($result->params,$post);
            //check to see if the file exists

            $fuObj = new FileUpload();
            $file_exists = $fuObj->does_file_exist($user_id,$post['fileId']);

            if($file_exists) {
                try {
                    $iObj->import($user_id,$post);
                } catch(Exception $e) {
                    $pObj->mark_failed($user_id,$process_name,$e->getMessage());
                    
                    throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
                }
                
                //mark process as completed.
                $pObj->set_complete($user_id,$process_id);
            } else {
                //file doesn't exist
                $pObj->mark_failed($user_id,$process_name,'The file no longer exists.  Please start the upload process again.');
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

In the `handle()` function above, the following happens:

1. the details of the process are retrieved using the `get_process()` function
2. if the process is valid, it tries running the import in a try/catch statement
3. if the import fails, the `mark_failed()` function is called and updates the `failed` column in the `processes` table to true and adds the exception message
4. the job is marked as completed through the `set_complete()` function.  This sets the `completed` column in the `processes` table to `true.

The functions in the `Processes` Model are as follows:

```
<?php

public function add_process($d)
    {
        Process::insert($d);
    }

public function get_process($user_id, $process_name)
    {
        /**
         * Note: 8/18/2020 - I added the lockForUpdate() to try and prevent errors where the process table was getting locked.
         * I think there was an issue where on some occasions either the process would get run twice or somehow the row got selected twice and it was causing a table deadlock
         **/
        return Process::where('user_id',$user_id)->where('process_name',$process_name)->lockForUpdate()->first();
    }

public function set_complete($user_id, $id)
    {
        $res = Process::where('user_id',$user_id)->where('id',$id)->update(['completed'=>true]);
    }

public function mark_failed($user_id, $name, $msg='')
    {
        Process::where('user_id',$user_id)->where('process_name',$name)->update(['failed'=>true,'failed_text'=>$msg]);
    }

?>
```

**The Problem (Full version)**

The issue is I'm getting a deadlock on the `processes` table `select` call that's initially made in the `ImportFile` job.  What I've been able to deduce from watching logs and reading the documentation is this:

1. The background job loads and it gets the process information via the `Process::get_process()` function
2. Something will go wrong in the `try` statement and the job will fail without calling the `mark_failed` or `set_complete` functions for whatever reason
3. The job will retry but the previous instance of the job that failed still has a lock on that `SELECT` from the `processes` table.  <-- this is where I think the main issue is
4. The loading script I have which checks the `processes` table for a completed or failed flag hits the deadlocked row and causes another backup.
5. If the user leaves the "loading" page active, it could cause a huge number of queries waiting to select that deadlocked row.

I'm not sure how to get around the issue of the lock remaining on that row after the job has failed.  I tried adding `->lockForUpdate()` on the `get_process() SELECT` statement and that didn't seem to make any difference.

Eventually I'll see a bunch of these statements failing in my logs:
`SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired (SQL: select * from "processes" where "user_id" = 337662 and "process_name" = 337662_1597818273 limit 1 for update) | /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php`

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue and found a workaround?  Or do you see anything obviously wrong in my code that might be causing these deadlocks?

Other information: The app is currently running on Heroku with the Postgres Standard-3 database.

Comment: Please read this:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE  I think you are diagnosing the problem correctly.  Solving your immediate problem requires either a `SKIP LOCKED`, which will return nothing from the query, or `NOWAIT`, which will throw an error immediately.  It is up to you to decide which is more appropriate.  You will need to figure out why your handler is choking.  Is there a reason you do not have a `finally` to rollback the transaction as part of that `try. . .catch`?

Comment: @MikeOrganek thanks for the information.  This gives me a good starting point for doing some more debugging.  I've also added the `finally` block to the `try...catch` statement which should help at least with marking the process as completed (whether it failed or not)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is experiencing a similar issue and comes across this question in the future, here's what I ended up finding out and doing.

The underlying issue was connections to a table remaining open when a background job failed and exited.  These open connections were causing a lock on the table and when I was checking on the status of the job, that `SELECT` statement wouldn't execute since the row was locked.  These queries would eventually queue up and cause the whole database to get backed up and eventually shut down.

The solution was mainly to debug why the jobs were failing.  Thanks to the comment from Mike Organek, I added a `finally` clause to my `try...catch` statements which at least kept the jobs from failing.  After some additional debugging I could actually log and fix the reason the jobs were failing.